# Percentage calculation in algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Appraiser Leung is working on an appraisal for $44$ rabble road. Leung is trying to determine the price trend in the neighbourhood in order to make the necessary time adjustments to comparable sold properties. He has come across a property in the area that sold 7 months ago for $269, 500.00$ and resold one month ago for $291,200.00$. based on these two sales, what is the monthly percentage that Leung would use when calculating the time adjustment (rounded to 2 decimal places) ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: how many months between the sales? If the price is multiplied by $r$ after one month, what is it multiplied by for that many months?